# @Asynchronous with JMS

Tags: java, asynchronous, glassfish, jms

is it possible to send JMS message from @Asynchroonous method? If yes, how? If I call send message everything finish fine, witouth exceptions but MDB are not invoked. But if I call another method not marked as @Asynchronous, MDB are invoked. So is it possible to send to JMS from @Asynchronous method?

```
@Singleton
class MessageProducer{

     @Resource (mappedName = "...")
     private ConnectionFactory qFactory;

     @Resource(mappedName = "...")
     private Topic topic;

     @Asynchronous
     public void sendMessage(){
            qConn = qFactory.createConnection();
            session = qConn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer prod = session.createProducer(topic);
            prod.send(someObject);
            prod.close();
            session.close();
            qConn.close();
     }
}
```